# Rust Function Signature resulting in: error: expected `::`, found `,`

Tags: rust

## Context

I'm writing a mini-shell in rust to learn the language. I'm effectively brand new to the language at this point so I expect this to be a fairly basic misunderstanding.

## Short Question

I'm writing a function signature
Where

```
fn process_line(line: <String>, built_ins: HashMap<&str, BuiltinFn>) -> i8 {
```

and

```
fn process_line(line: <String>) -> i8
```

results in the following error shown in the next two sections but this signature

```
fn process_line() -> i8 {
```

succeeds and I'm not sure why. I've tried looking up what the `::` operator in rust is and searching for this particular message for rust function signatures and I don't really understand the issue here. The best I've been able to guess is that the compiler expects me to define a set of traits for the arguments?

## Two Argument Error Message

```
cargo test
   Compiling rust_bash v0.1.0 (/Users/Alex.LordThorsen/git/misc/rust_bash)
error: expected `::`, found `,`
  --> src/main.rs:26:31
   |
26 | fn process_line(line: <String>, built_ins: HashMap<&str, BuiltinFn>) -> i8 {
   |                               ^ expected `::`

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `rust_bash`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

## One Argument Error Message

```
cargo test
   Compiling rust_bash v0.1.0 (/Users/Alex.LordThorsen/git/misc/rust_bash)
error: expected `::`, found `)`
  --> src/main.rs:27:31
   |
27 | fn process_line(line: <String>) -> i8 {
   |                               ^ expected `::`

warning: unused import: `std::collections::HashMap`
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 | use std::collections::HashMap;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

warning: unused import: `BuiltinFn`
  --> src/main.rs:22:32
   |
22 | use builtins::{load_built_ins, BuiltinFn};
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error; 2 warnings emitted

error: could not compile `rust_bash`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

## Project Structure

```
~/git/misc/rust_bash/src :)% tree
.
├── README.md
├── argument_parsing.rs
├── builtins
│   ├── cd.rs
│   ├── echo.rs
│   └── mod.rs
└── main.rs
```

## main.rs

```
mod argument_parsing;
mod builtins;

use std::env;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use log;

use simple_logger::SimpleLogger;
use text_io::read;

use argument_parsing::parse_arguments;
use builtins::{load_built_ins, BuiltinFn};



//fn process_line(line: <String>, built_ins: HashMap<&str, BuiltinFn>) -> i8 {
fn process_line(line: <String>) -> i8 {
    // If the requested argument is a builtin don't fork and directly run the
    // requested action.

    // If the function is not a builtin then first fork, have the child run the
    // command while the parent waits, and set the current exit status to the
    // commands exit status.
    return 0
}

fn process_io() {
    let mut line = String::new();
    let mut status_code: i8;
    // Loading Built ins here so that it's loaded once and passing to
    // process_line.
    let built_ins = load_built_ins();
    loop {
        // TODO: Add a prompt here.
        line = read!();
        log::debug!("Line to Process: {}", line);
        if line == "exit" {
            break;
        }
        status_code = process_line(line, built_ins)
    }
}

fn main() {
    SimpleLogger::from_env().init().unwrap();
    // env::args().collect() will automatically do quote groupings for us.
    // Technically this might mean we read the args string twice? Might want to
    // look into that.
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let processed_args: Vec<String>;

    log::debug!("Args Before Processing: {:?}", args);
    processed_args = parse_arguments(args);
    log::debug!("Processed Args: {:?}", processed_args);

    if processed_args.len() == 0 {
        process_io();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `<String>` supposed to be here?

Comment: let mut line = String::new(); that's populated from line = read!(); and passed to the function process_line.

Comment: I'm talking about function signature. `<String>` isn't a valid type on it's own, only as a part of <Type as Trait>::AssociatedType.

Comment: Ah, I'm assuming I actually want &str since this function will only need to read the string then. How does one know if a type requires the <type as trait>::AssocuatedType pattern?

Comment: The issue is `<String>` vs `String`. The `<>` wrapper does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<String>` is not valid syntax for a type. Instead of

```rust
fn process_line(line: <String>) -> i8
```

you need:

```rust
fn process_line(line: String) -> i8
```

Angle brackets are never be used around a type *by itself.* Angle brackets are used for *parameters* to another type, as in your other usage `HashMap<&str, BuiltinFn>` where `HashMap` is the generic type and `&str, BuiltinFn` are the two parameters — that's correct syntax, and this is not.

---

Angle brackets are also used for referring to associated items (functions, types, or constants declared inside an `impl` block) in certain cases, like the associated type `<T as Iterator>::Item` or the associated function `<[i32]>::get`, but that's the only time you'll see an `<` being entirely *before* a type name without being also *after* one. **That's why** the parser told you "expected `::`": given that when parsing the type it saw a `<` first, it wanted an `>::` afterward.